# Need help regarding a firebase Query to append the values of a key from multiple nodes of the same child

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve the value for each category and then add it to the MPAndroid Pie Chart module that I'm using.

Basically, I want to:

1. Get value for Communication from month 1
2. Get value for Communication from month 2
3. Add the values
4. Add it to my List Cats with Cats.add(new PieEntry(my_total_value,category_name);

This is what I'm currently implementing for my radar chart but it duplicates each category for each month because it adds a value to the list for each month:

```
 public void setYearRadar(final String date, boolean incexp)
{
    final String incexpt;

    if(incexp)
    {
        incexpt="Expense";
    }
    else
    {
        incexpt="Income";
    }


    final DatabaseReference dRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    dRef.child("Users")
            .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
            .child(date)
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                {
                    Rcats = new ArrayList<>();
                    Rlabel = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (DataSnapshot d: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                    {
                        Query expQuery =
                                dRef.child("Users")
                                        .child(cAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())
                                        .child(date)
                                        .child(d.getKey())
                                        .child("Transactions")
                                        .child("Category")
                                        .child(incexpt);

                        if(expQuery!=null)
                        {
                            expQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                                {
                                    Float x=0f;
                                    for (DataSnapshot d : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                                    {
                                        x = x + Float.parseFloat(d.getValue().toString());
                                    }
                                    for (DataSnapshot d : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                                    {
                                        if (Float.parseFloat(d.getValue().toString()) > 0.0)
                                        {
                                            Rcats.add(new RadarEntry(Float.parseFloat(d.getValue().toString())/x*100, d.getKey())); //Adding value and converting to percentage
                                            Rlabel.add(d.getKey());
                                        }
                                    }
                                    if (!Rcats.isEmpty()&& Rcats.size()>2 && Rlabel.size()>2)
                                    {

                                        initRadarChart(Rcats,Rlabel,date,incexpt);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        rc.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
                                {

                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
                {

                }
            });

}
```

This is how my Categories look like
[image: My Firebase Structure]

This is my whole data structure
[image: The whole structure]

And here is the even more messy PieChart class

```
    private void setYearPie(final String date, Boolean incexp)
{
    final String incexpt;

    if(incexp)
    {
        incexpt="Expense";
    }
    else
    {
        incexpt="Income";
    }


    final DatabaseReference dRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    dRef.child("Users")
            .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
            .child(date)
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                {
                    Ycats = new ArrayList<>();
                    Ylabel = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (DataSnapshot d: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                    {
                        Query expQuery =
                                dRef.child("Users")
                                        .child(cAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())
                                        .child(date)
                                        .child(d.getKey())
                                        .child("Transactions")
                                        .child("Category")
                                        .child(incexpt);

                        if(expQuery!=null)
                        {
                            expQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                                {
                                     for (DataSnapshot d : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                                    {
                                        if (Float.parseFloat(d.getValue().toString()) > 0.0)
                                        {
                                            Ycats.add(new PieEntry(Float.parseFloat(d.getValue().toString()), d.getKey()));
                                            Ylabel.add(d.getKey());
                                            x = 0f;
                                        }
                                        if (!Ycats.isEmpty())
                                        {

                                            initPieChart(Ycats,Ylabel,date,incexpt);
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            //pc.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
                                {

                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
                {

                }
            });


}
```

My expected outcome is that I want to create the final list for each category entered once with values from each month for that category, Eg. if in month 1 food=400 and in month 2 food=800 then I want my final list added as {1200,food}

I'm at my wits end here, and my brain has stopped working, I'd really appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: And what are you expecting to achieve? Can you post the expected structure in the question too?

Comment: I'm sorry if my question wasn't well worded, I want to create the final list for each category entered once with values from each month for that category, eg. if month 1 food=400 and month 2 food=800 then I want my final list added as {1200,food} @noob